# Is there a way to clear everything before starting in Mathematica?

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

In MATLAB there is the function *clear* to delete all current variables. This is very useful if you start something totally new and don't want to get conflicts with earlier calculations. I'm searching something similar for Mathematica now, but I couldn't find anything except of *Clear[VAR]* which removes only the variable *VAR*.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I recommend one of two methods:

#### 1. Keyboard shortcut to Quit[] the kernel

There is a system file `KeyEventTranslations.tr` that you can edit to customize keyboard shortcuts.  I, as others, have added <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd> to `Quit[]` the kernel, allowing for a rapid clearing of all sessions variables.  For more information on setting this up, see:

- [Customizing Mathematica shortcuts](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4209405/618728)

#### 2. Give the new Notebook a unique context

In Mathematica, the current `$Context` defines what [Context](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/Contexts.html) unqualified symbol names belong to.  By giving a new Notebook a unique Context, which is easily done through the `Evaluation` menu, the symbols used in that Notebook will not collide with unqualified symbols in other Notebooks.  See the following question for more detailed information:

- [Mathematica - Separating Notebooks](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4896011/618728)

Comment: Could you summarize the two methods here? It's not generally nice to simply link to an existing post. If it really is answered by those exactly, then we should close this as a duplicate.

Comment: @yoda my understanding of correct answering differs from your own.  I do not wish to duplicate existing answers, and I am not linking to external sources, but rather StackOverflow itself.  Further, I do not believe this is a duplicate question, and should not be closed.  Would it be better if I linked to specific answers rather than those questions?  If you feel I my understanding requires correction, please explain why.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/113437/answering-questions-with-links-to-other-answers-on-stackoverflow/113444#113444

Comment: +1 - I too approve of this answer, as this is a very good example (good grammar, formatting, content, and references to support answer) of the kind of answer that StackOverflow likes to receive. Good work!

Answer (score 17):

You can use `ClearAll` to clear the variables and their attributes in your `Global` context (default) like so:

```
ClearAll["Global`*"]
```

If you're working inside a different context (e.g., notebook specific context or cell group specific context), you can do

```
ClearAll[Evaluate[Context[] <> "*"]]
```

If you want to *remove* all symbols from the kernel so that Mathematica doesn't recognize them anymore, you can use `Remove[]` similar to the above two examples.

Barring these, you can always quit the kernel with `Quit[]` which will remove all symbols. A fresh kernel will be initiated the next time you evaluate something.

Answer (score 14):

I just realized that you might not know that unlike MATLAB, Mathematica is designed to run as two separate processes:  the Front End is the user interface, and lets you work with notebooks.  The Kernel does the computations.  You can quit the kernel without affecting the front end, or even start more than one kernel for different notebooks, or start a kernel on a remote computer and use it with a local front end.

---

I believe that the only reliable way to clean everything is to `Quit` the kernel and re-start it (which is automatic).  There are just too many things that can get modified apart from user variables/functions (including `In`/`Out`, loaded packages, system caches, etc.).  So if you need a truly fresh start, I recommend `Quit`.

For a "soft" reset, @yoda already mentioned `` ClearAll["Global`*"] ``.  There's the `` << Utilities`CleanSlate` `` package, which automates a little bit more than this.  You can read the package docs inside the `AddOns\ExtraPackages\Utilities\CleanSlate.m` file.

In short, `CleanSlate[]` will attempt to take you back to the kernel state when the package was loaded.  `ClearInOut[]` will clear `In` and `Out` to save memory.

I haven't used this package in years (except for the `ClearInOut[]` functionality), as the Mathematica kernel starts up quickly on modern computers, so I just use `Quit`.  So I can't tell you how well it works.

Comment: is it possible then by just Quiting (rebooting) the kernel, that the front end might itself remember something in its own little space, which would not be removed/cleared by rebooting the kernel?  I also use this method of reboot the kernel each time when I want to really make sure things are cleaned up. But I always wondered if the front-end might still remember something. When I want to really really make sure, I just restart all of Mathematica itself.

Comment: @Nasser To my knowledge, strictly speaking the Front End won't remember anything.  However, it may happen that you have a notebook with dynamic content open, and as soon as this content comes into view, it causes the front end to re-launch the kernel and evaluate whatever is defined in the dynamic object to be evaluated.  The confusing part is that this only happens when the dynamic things come into view, so it might seem a bit "indeterministic" if you don't know what's happening.  I myself don't restart the front end to have a clean session.