# Is there any command or routine to clean screen in Mathematica?

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I am seeking some command or some routine that allows cleaning the work area (screen) so that the results are presented in a clean screen. Command is not to clean things like variables, it is with the screen.

in other languages ​​such Qbasic it was `cls`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a way to clear everything before starting in Mathematica?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8260217/is-there-a-way-to-clear-everything-before-starting-in-mathematica)

Answer (score 2):

This function enables clearing of the current notebook :-

```
cls := Module[{nb},
  nb = EvaluationNotebook[];
  SelectionMove[nb, All, Notebook];
  NotebookDelete@nb]
```

Once it is evaluated, possibly in an initialisation file, just type `cls` to run.

**Edit**

Further to zeros comment, this will display the results in a fresh window.

```
Clear["Global`*"]
a = Input["ingrese a , a distinto de cero"];
b = Input["ingrese b "];
c = Input["ingrese c "];
CreateDocument[
  ExpressionCell[
   Row[{"La funcion es : y = ", TraditionalForm[a*"x"^"2" + b*"x" + c]}],
   "Print"],
  NotebookFileName -> "C:\\Users\\yo\\Desktop\\nb\\prueba.nb"];
```

If you also want to close the initial notebook you can add `NotebookClose[]` at the end.

Also, if you want to close all other notebooks except the final output notebook you can add the following at the beginning :-

```
NotebookClose /@ DeleteCases[Notebooks[], EvaluationNotebook[]];
```

Note, you are only clearing variables in the global context.  To clear variables in the *current* context you can use `Clear@Evaluate[$Context <> "*"]`.

Comment: hi there
I have tried to implement what you suggested, but as routine deletes the entire book, I tried to call again for a new execution, but it does not work, I send some of the code for you to see, you should have something like "if like other execution press "s" "

Comment: Clear["Global`*"]
cls := Module[{nb}, nb = EvaluationNotebook[];
  SelectionMove[nb, All, Notebook];
  NotebookDelete@nb]
a = Input["ingrese a , a distinto de cero"];
b = Input["ingrese b "];
c = Input["ingrese c "];
cls
Print["La funcion es : y= ", 
 a*"\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(x\), \(2\)]\)" + b*"x" + c // 
  TraditionalForm]
NotebookOpen["C:\Users\yo\Desktop\nb\prueba.nb"];

Comment: Thanks for your help, but I can not acceptable, or do not express well in question

Answer (score 2):

When in a notebook, `<Control>+a` will select all cells and `<delete>` will remove them from your screen, and it will appear as if you have just opened Mathematica. You can't autoamte this (put it in a script), but it's handy if you're just doing some calculations.

The cells don't actually go away entirely, you can still use any variables they assigned or access their results with `%`.

Comment: exactly the answer I was looking for! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I don’t know of anything built into Mathematica to do this, but if you’re working in a Unix terminal like xterm, you can call an external program to clear the screen for you:

```
Run["tput cl"]
```

or more succintly,

```
!tput cl
```

This looks up the current terminal’s [control code for clearing the screen](http://www.manpagez.com/man/5/terminfo/) and writes it to stdout, clearing the screen for you.

You can also run the `clear` command if you have it:

```
!clear
```

If you want a pure-Mathematica way to do this, well, there’s probably some way to use SymbolicC to call `terminfo` functions directly, but I don’t know how to do that. What I can do is to find out what the control code for clearing the screen is and hard-code it into Mathematica code.

On my xterm-compatible terminal,

```
$ tput cl | hexdump -C
00000000  1b 5b 48 1b 5b 32 4a                              |.[H.[2J|
00000007
```

so this also clears the screen:

```
BinaryWrite[Streams[][[1]],
 FromDigits[#, 16] & /@ {"1b", "5b", "48", "1b", "5b", "32", "4a"}]
```

I guess you could wrap that in a function or something for ease of use.

Comment: hi, thanks for answering
the truth you do not quite understand, I use Mathematica in win 7, as the program does what I need for recording that starts the execution of the program with a clean screen (I could not or did not understand what you post) , I reply through a translator ... I appreciate any help in this general area.

Comment: Thanks for your help, but I can not acceptable, or do not express well in question